# $n^3+n+1$ is perfect square

Tags: elementary-number-theory

find all positive integers $n$ for which $n^3+n+1$ is a perfect square

$n^3+n+1$ is odd so $8|n^3+n$ so $8|n(n^2+1)$ if $2|n^2+1$  ,$v_2(n^2+1)=1$ so $n$ must be even, contradiction. So $8\mid n.$

Also by checking $\bmod7$ we understand that $n=0\pmod7$ or $n=2\pmod7$ so $56\mid n$ or $n=16\pmod{56}$ also $72$ is an answer!
Another approach: add $n^2$ to both sides: $(n+1)(n^2+1)=a^2+n^2$ It's obvios that $\gcd(a,n)=1$ so by vitek lemma all prime divisors of $a^2+n^2$ are $4k+1$ so the same for prime divisors of $n+1$.

Another approach: let $[\sqrt{n^3}]=c$
So $n^3<(c+1)^2$ so $n+1<c$ so $n^3+n+1<(c+2)^2$ so if $n^3+n+1=a^2$ $a$ is less than or equal to $c+1$ on the other hand it's obvious that $a>c$ so $a=c+1$

Answer (score 1):

The solutions correspond to the integral points on the elliptic curve
$$
y^2=x^3+x+1,
$$
which are given by
$$
(0,\pm 1),\;(72,\pm 611).
$$
See for example [LMFDB](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/496/a/1).

It is easy to obtain the points $(72,\pm 611)$ starting from $(0,1)$, see

[Find an affine point on $E:y^2=x^3+x+1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2078589/find-an-affine-point-on-ey2-x3x1?noredirect=1)

but it requires more on elliptic curves to show that there are no other integer points.

Comment: It would have been more informative to tell how those solutions were found, and how to show there are no others.

Comment: Thanks, I hoped an elementary solution exists! I'd be glad if someone presents an elementary solution

Comment: -1  Please see this [meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19548/242) on "answers" composed purely mechanically.

Comment: @BillDubuque There are other posts, which have a very similar answer, see for example the answer by Pete Clark [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30501/integer-solutions-of-n2n1-m3), where the best thing to do is to use a CAS, it seems. Here you did not object so far. I will try to find a better solution, of course.